# Updating protected serve url path with patterns for django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-urls

How do you use this code in the current (1.11) version of Django? The code below uses patterns module but as I googled it was removed in 1.10.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings


@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], protected_serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Here's the source tutorial [link](https://blog.majsky.cz/django-protected-media-files/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django 1.8+, urlpatterns should be a list ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns)). Remove the `patterns` import as well.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], protected_serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

Comment: Do you have any clue why this solution is working locally for me but when I push my code to my server, I'm still able to access media files through the direct URL while being logged out?

Comment: In production the media/static files are normally served by your server (e.g. Nginx/Apache) instead of Django.

Comment: @W.White if you need more help please ask another question I can't help you in the comments here.

Comment: thanks. I will look into that first. If I'm not able to fix it, I will ask a question!